# Casting EditText into hexadecimal array on android

Tags: android, bitmap, hex

I'm working on a project for school on android studio.

I have 2 EditText fields where I have an input. 
i want to transforme those 2 EditTexts into an Hexadecimal bitmaparray. The purpous is to send this Bitmap to another device over bluetooth (this part works cause i can sent a existing Bitmap but can't create one).

Thank you for the help guy's

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
EditText view = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmapView = view.getDrawingCache();
```